# ¿Cómo comparar automáticamente el tamaño de dos ficheros en Bash o Zsh?

Tags: bash, archivo, zsh

Quiero escribir un optimizador para mis documentos compartidos utilizando herramientas externas. La idea es procesar un fichero con un programa, lo cual me va a dejar con una copia que puede o no ser de menor tamaño. Quisiera poder comparar automáticamente el tamaño de ambos (ficheros de entrada y salida), borrar el más grande y conservar el otro.

¿Alguna pista de cómo hacerlo? Hasta ahora uso `du -b` para averiguar el tamaño pero no consigo separar el número del nombre.

Sé que es posible utilizar Sed para esto pero francamente no sé por dónde empezar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta sería una forma de hacerlo con awk.
Toma como input el formato de `ls -l` y el nombre de los dos archivos.

```
ls -l arch1.txt arch2.txt | awk 'BEGIN{arch="";sz=-1;}{if(sz==-1){arch=$9;sz=$5;} if($5>sz){arch=$9;sz="$5";}}END{print arch}'
```

`$5` es el campo 5 de la salida de `ls -l` osea el tamaño.
`$9` es el nombre del archivo.

Se inicializan las variables, el tamaño a un valor sin sentido.
Luego la primera linea del resultado del `ls`, va a setearse como el archivo de mayor tamaño y si el segundo es mayor lo va a reemplazar cuando se procese la segunda linea.
Finalmente imprime el nombre del archivo mas chico.

EDICION I

Gracias @fedorqui por el feedback.
Versión simplificada de @fedorqui (Ver comentarios abajo):

```
awk 'NR==1 {sz1=$5; arch=$9; next} {if ($5 > sz1) {print $9} else {print arch}}'
```

Nota: Hay varios articulos explicando que la salida del comando ls puede variar, por lo que esta solución puede no funcionar en todos los casos.
Dejo un link a uno de los articulos como para dar idea de los posibles problemas: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Comment: Parsear el resultado de `ls` es bastante peligroso, pues no es consistente. En cualquier caso, si vas a hacerlo con Awk puedes simplificarlo bastante diciendo algo así como: `awk 'NR==1 {sz1=$5; arch=$9; next} {if ($5 > sz1) {print $9} else {print arch}}'`. Básicamente, con NR==1 miras si es la primera línea. No hace falta usar ni BEGIN ni END para todo esto.

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurren varias opciones:

### Con un *command substitution*

Puedes usar `[[ <comando> ]] && <que pasa si es verdadero> || <que pasa si es falso>`. Por ejemplo:

```
a1=archivo3 a2=archivo2; [[ $(stat -c "%s" "$a1") -gt $(stat -c "%s" "$a2") ]] && echo "$a1 mayor" || echo "$a1 no es mayor"
```

Lo que hago es usar `stat -c` para obtener la salida de los dos archivos, estos los pongo en un *command substitution*.

Nótese que la sentencia es del tipo `[[ condición ]] && caso_positivo || caso_negativo`: El estado de salida del *built-in* `[[` definirá, si es 0, si se ejecuta lo que está después de `&&` y antes de `||` o, en caso de que sea diferente de 0, si se ejecuta lo que está después de `||`.

Esto lo puedes poner dentro de un bloque if ; then; ... ; else; fi.

Por ejemplo:

```
a1=archivo1
a2=archivo2

if [[ $(stat -c "%s" "$a1") -gt $(stat -c "%s" "$a2") ]]
then
    echo "$a1 es más grande"
else
    echo "$a1 no es más grande"
fi
```

### Con `du` y construyendo la condicional.

Podrías utilizar esto:

```
a1=archivo3 a2=archivo2; [ $(du -b "$a1" "$a2" | awk -v ORS=' -gt ' '{print $1}' | sed 's/ -gt $//g') ] \
&& echo "$a1 es mayor" \
|| echo "$a1 no es mayor"
```

Que es semejante al anterior pero ejecuta la condición `[ <tamano_de_archivo1 -gt tamano_de_archivo2> ] && <si es mayor> || <si no es mayor>`.

Para esto utilizo `awk` y su variable interner `ORS` para que lo separe con la cadena `-gt`. Luego con `sed` elimino la última cadena `-gt`. Dígamos que con esta propuesta construyo la propia condicional, construyo la parte del código.

Esto está relacionado con la metaprogramación.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el siguiente script en bash (`compara.sh`)

```sh
FILESIZE1=$(stat -c%s $1)
FILESIZE2=$(stat -c%s $2)

if [ ${FILESIZE1} -ne ${FILESIZE2} ]; then
   echo Los ficheros son diferentes
   if [ ${FILESIZE1} -gt ${FILESIZE2} ]; then
       echo "El fichero $1 es mayor que el $2 y será eliminado"
       rm $1
   else
       echo "El fichero $2 es mayor que el $1 y será eliminado"
       rm $2
   fi
else
    echo "Los ficheros son iguales"
fi
```

Para lanzarlo pásale los ficheros como parámetros:

```
compara.sh  fichero1 fichero2
```

Y la salida, en el caso de que fichero1 fuera más grande, será:

```
Los ficheros son diferentes
El fichero fichero1 es mayor que el fichero2 y será eliminado
```

Otra opción similar pero en una línea, basada en el comando `test`:

```
echo fichero1.jpg fichero2.jpg | xargs -n2 sh -c '([ $(stat -c%s $0) -gt $(stat -c%s $1) ] && rm -f "$0") || ([ $(stat -c%s $1) -gt $(stat -c%s $0) ] && rm -f "$1")'
```

Comment: Gracias Roberto! No conocía nada del comando 'stat' así que ahora tengo material de lectura.

Comment: Yo no he sido, pero supongo que el que lo hizo (si no fue por accidente) vio que la pregunta no es cómo saber si dos ficheros son iguales o diferentes, sino cuál de los dos es más grande para borrarlo y dejar el más pequeño. Gracias igual por tu respuesta, me ha enseñado mucho que planeo utilizar más tarde en otros scripts

Comment: Gracias Gonzalo, eso lo explica, la adaptaré entonces, la leí demasiado rápido ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Dejo una alternativa usando perl, que creo que ofrece estas ventajas:

- No parsea el comando `ls`
- Es más fácil de leer (aunque esto es algo subjetivo)
- Funciona con cualquier cantidad de ficheros como entrada. Dirá el más grande de todos
- Los ficheros se ponen al final, con lo que se puede utilizar el autocompletar en caso de usarlo de manera interactiva, e incluso utilizar un alias.

Este sería el comando (donde a, b, c, d, ... son los ficheros)

```
perl -e '@_ = sort { (-s $b) - (-s $a) } @ARGV; print shift @_' a b c d)
```

Si necesitas guardar el nombre en una variable, puedes utilizar cualquiera de estas dos opciones:

```
FICHERO=$(perl -e '@_ = sort { (-s $b) - (-s $a) } @ARGV; print shift @_' a b c d)
FICHERO=`perl -e '@_ = sort { (-s $b) - (-s $a) } @ARGV; print shift @_' a b c d`
```

Finalmente, si quieres usarlo con un alias, puedes definirlo así:

```
$ alias masgrande=$'perl -e \'@_ = sort { (-s $b) - (-s $a) } @ARGV; print shift @_\''

$ masgrande a b c d

d
```

Comment: ¡Súper bien con `perl`!. Muy buen aporte al tag de `bash`. Sólo que considero (espero que tú también), que sería mejor utilizar el *command substitution* con `$( command )` en lugar de usar las comillas invertidas `\` comando \``.

Comment: En este caso usé comillas invertidas para evitar escapar las comilals simples del propio comando perl (como las que se pueden ver en el ejemplo del `alias`, que lo *afeaban* un poco :-) )

Comment: No, cuando usas las comillas invertidas (en el segundo código con la variable `FICHERO`) corres un *command substitution*; no son para escapar, en cambio, en el `alias`, así si simplemente corres un "short-cut".
Lo que yo decía era que en el segundo caso, uses el *command substitution* así: `FICHERO=$(perl -e '($f1, $f2) = @ARGV; print -s $f1 > -s $f2 ? $f1 : $f2' fichero1 fichero2)`

Comment: Sí, lo que quería decir es que como en perl las variables se inicial con dolar, pensaba que al usar `$('...')` tenía que poner todo el comando con comillas, lo cual me hubiera obligado a escapar las comillas del propio comando perl y de ahí que optase por usar las comillas invertidas en su lugar. Ahora veo que no es necesario `$(...)` En cualquier caso, particularmente me gusta más usar comillas invertidas (supongo que porque suelo usar perl y en los scripts de perl también se pueden usar para capturar la salida de un comando)